# not able to get path of "android.intent.action.SEND" intent properly

Tags: android, android-intent

I am able to pass the path to another class through the following code

```
private void sendImageFromCameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.startsWith("image/")) {
        Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            String path = imageUri.getPath();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageShared = true;
            inputPanel.sendImage(path);
        }
    }
}
```

But in the other class the following check fails

```
 public int sendImage(String path) {
    if (path != null && new File(path).isFile()) {
     // code to send image - works fine when adding an attachment

     return 1;
   }
   else return -1
```

The path is shown in the toast but I get a -1 as return value

Comment: Please post more code, currently it is not clear where the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the getPath to

```
String path = FileUtils.getPath(getActivity(), imageUri);
```